# Microdisplacements with adaptive subdivision turning black

Tags: texturing, subdivision-surface

I followed a microdisplacements tutorial on Blender Guru and I was able to create a texture fine. Here is a picture.[image]

And then I turned on Adaptive subdivision. Here is a picture of what happened.[image]

I know that this question has been asked before but I am using blender 2.79 so it should be fixed, right? Please let me know you ideas. Thanks

Comment: Try using *object space* on your normal map node instead of tangent.

Comment: @Timaroberts Write an answer.

Comment: @Dimali, have done so.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When using [adaptive subdivision](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/object_settings/adaptive_subdiv.html#adaptive-subdivision), your [normal map node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/vector/normal_map.html#normal-map-node) should not use *tangent space*, or your object will appear black. Instead, use *object space*, and it will render as expected.

Object Space:

[image]
[image]

Tangent Space:
[image]
[image]

While I am not certain of the reason for this behavior, it is marked as a [to do](https://developer.blender.org/T49159) item in the tracker at the moment, rather than a bug.